# If time in datetime is midnight 00:00:00 change to next day

Tags: r, time, time-series

I'm setting up a large dataset for time-series analysis. The data has a date start time and a date end-time.

The data was input as 24:00:00 for end-time I've now converted this to 00:00:00. I want to move all my end data that finishes at 00:00:00 forward by one day.

```
#Current database
id<-c("m1","m1","m1","m2","m2","m2","m3","m4","m4")
x<-c("2020-01-03 10:00:00","2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 
19:20:00","2020-01-05 10:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 
20:50:00","2020-01-06 06:30:00","2020-01-08 06:30:00","2020-01-08 
07:50:00")
start<-strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
y<-c("2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-03 
00:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-05 
00:00:00","2020-01-06 07:40:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00","2020-01-08 
08:55:00")
end<-strptime(y,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mydata<-data.frame(id,start,end)

#Output
id2<-c("m1","m1","m1","m2","m2","m2","m3","m4","m4")
x2<-c("2020-01-03 10:00:00","2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 
19:20:00","2020-01-05 10:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 
20:50:00","2020-01-06 06:30:00","2020-01-08 06:30:00","2020-01-08 
07:50:00")
start2<-strptime(x2,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
y2<-c("2020-01-03 16:00:00","2020-01-03 19:20:00","2020-01-04 
00:00:00","2020-01-05 15:20:00","2020-01-05 20:50:00","2020-01-06 
00:00:00","2020-01-06 07:40:00","2020-01-08 07:50:00","2020-01-08 
08:55:00")
end2<-strptime(y2,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mydata2<-data.frame(id2,start2,end2)
```

I expect the output for row 3 and row 6 to have moved date forward one day. Is it the "if" function or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` seems pretty straightforward. `ifelse` is vectorized:

```
library(lubridate)
mydata$end2 = as_datetime(ifelse(format(mydata$end, "%H:%M:%S") == "00:00:00", mydata$end + days(1), mydata$end), tz = Sys.timezone())
mydata
#   id               start                 end                end2
# 1 m1 2020-01-03 10:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 16:00:00
# 2 m1 2020-01-03 16:00:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-03 19:20:00
# 3 m1 2020-01-03 19:20:00 2020-01-03 00:00:00 2020-01-04 00:00:00
# 4 m2 2020-01-05 10:00:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 15:20:00
# 5 m2 2020-01-05 15:20:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 20:50:00
# 6 m2 2020-01-05 20:50:00 2020-01-05 00:00:00 2020-01-06 00:00:00
# 7 m3 2020-01-06 06:30:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00 2020-01-06 07:40:00
# 8 m4 2020-01-08 06:30:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 07:50:00
# 9 m4 2020-01-08 07:50:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00 2020-01-08 08:55:00
```

Answer (score 2):

As you asked for a "simpler way": `lubridate` package does this automatically for you (even for times over 24:00:00). If you are not familiar with it, check out this [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/lubridate.pdf) on RStudio website.

Date-times ending with 00:00:00 will stay on the same day and date-times ending with 24:00:00 will leap one day foward. Some examples:

```r
library(lubridate)

ymd_hms("2019-07-30 00:00:00")
[1] "2019-07-30 UTC"

ymd_hms("2019-07-30 24:00:00")
[1] "2019-07-31 UTC"

ymd_hms("2019-07-30 24:01:05")
[1] "2019-07-31 00:01:05 UTC"
```

I really recommend using this package, as it makes working with date-times *much less* of a hassle. There is a small trade-off on consistency over perfomance, but I think it is not an issue on most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in `POSIXct` than adding `86400` is equivalent to adding a day. Instead of using an if statement you could vectorize it.

```
library(lubridate)
my_hours <- rep(0, nrow(mydata))
my_hours[which(hour(mydata$end)==0)] <- 86400
my_hours <- which(hour(mydata$end) == 0)
mydata$end <- mydata$end + my_hours

mydata$end == mydata2$end2
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Might run into issues with leap seconds?